# How to solve a PDE with boundary condition of $u_x=A$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem

To have straightforward and homogeneous boundary conditions for solving
$$u_t = \kappa u_{xx}$$
with boundary conditions of
$$u_x(0,t)=A\\
u_x(L,t)=0$$
To solve the PDE with homogenous boundaries,
$$u(x,t) = w(x) + \nu(x,t)$$
where $w(x)$ is time-independent steady state condition. Then solution for $\nu(x,t)$ with new boundary conditions of 
$$\nu(0)=\nu(L)=0$$ by the method of separation of the varaibles $\nu(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, the general solution is
$$X(x)=a \cos \lambda x + b \sin \lambda x$$
by applying the boundary conditions, the solution is

$$\nu(x,t)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n e^{-t\kappa(n\pi/L)^2} \sin\left( \frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) \\
b_n=\frac{2}{L} \int_0^L f(x) \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) \,\mathrm{d}x$$

For deriving $f(x)$, we use the boundary condition of
$$u(x,0) = f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin(n \pi x)$$

How do we find $u(x,0)$ from the original boundary condition of $u_x=A$?

Comment: You should derive the conditions for your coefficients yourself. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749780/fourier-series-coefficients-in-pdes/1749839#1749839), it might help clear up any confusion. Also, how did you get a sine series with a Neumann boundary condition?

Comment: @Mattos I try to derive the coefficient similar to your approach in that answer, but I do not know $f(x)$. When the boundary conditions are simple as $u(0)=T_1,u(L)=T_2$, then, $f(x)=(T_2-T_1)x$, but what is $f(x)$  in this case? By separting the variable, $\nu(x,t)=a\sin\lambda x + b \sin \lambda x$, and with the boundary conditions of $\nu(0)=\nu(L)=0$, the sine series obtains.

Comment: $u(x,0) = w(0) + \nu(x,0) = f(x)$ i.e your initial condition. $f(x)$ is not the solution you have just stated. The form of $f(x)$ must be given to you explicitly in order to compute the Fourier coefficients explicitly. Otherwise, the coefficients are just given by the formula you stated in your post.

Comment: I think you should _start from the beginning of the problem again_ and apply your Neumann boundary conditions as you have done with your Dirichlet conditions. This might clear up any confusion.

Comment: @Mattos I edited the question. Does it make sense now? It is the entire problem. How to do it from here?